# IOS/Objective-C: Increase size of special character string used as title for button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I would like to increase the size of the title for a button, the catch being that it is not a system font but a specal character made from a constant.

Is there a way to do this?

The normal way to set the size of the button title is not changing the font size because it requires me to specify a normal font such as helvetica.

```
NSString *const PRIORITY = @"\u26A1";//this makes a lightning bolt
[_myButton setTitle:PRIORITY forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:24.0]];
```

Comment: The `⚡` character is a plain old Unicode character. You don't need to treat it special. You don't need a special font.

Comment: hmmm... works just fine in my quick test, using default UIButton font.

Comment: Perhaps font was the wrong word.  I just want the unicode character to display really large.  How would I do this?

Comment: Ok  I was mixing up font with special characters.  I found that a number of fonts including helvetica-bold provide support for my unicode character up to size 24.  I ended up using the following:  [_priorityButton.titleLabel setFont: [_priorityButton.titleLabel.font fontWithSize: 24]]; which leaves font unchanged.